# can "one' be substituted by "they" in a sentence?

Tags: pronouns, indefinite-pronouns

I'm wondering if this sentence makes sense. If more examples could be offered, that would be appreciated. Thank you.

> As long as **one** has a pastor certificate and gifts and can analyze the Bible, it means **they** are approved and anointed by God.

Comment: The author is probably trying to avoid using a gender specific pronoun such as "he".

Comment: @FumbleFingers In that one, it seems there was confusion over the referrent: not the case here, although it might still answer the question.

Comment: It's unclear and likely to confuse the reader, at least momentarily. I would immediately read your example wondering who it is that is approved and anointed by God as long as one has a pastor certificate, before reparsing it correctly. It's not incomprehensible, but definitely not advisable either. Stick with one pronoun (or at least one person/number) per entity per sentence.

Comment: Since *one* is already used as a genderless singular pronoun, why not just use it again in place of *they*?

Comment: @Lawrence Because that's horrible English. "They" is correct here. Its also natural. It avoids gender specificity WITHOUT drawing attention to the fact that it is doing this.  If you wrote "As long as one has a pastor certificate and gifts and can analyze the Bible, it means one is approved and anointed by God" then your Leftist agenda would be showing for all to see, you'd be calling yourself out as a LGBT activist essentially. Because "they" is natural English, the author of that sentence might not have an agenda; you don't know.

Comment: @developerwjk It might sound old-fashioned or maybe even pompous to use *one* twice in a sentence, but its association with the Left and with LGBT activism is new to me. What's the connection?

Comment: @developerwjk I'm astonished to find that for years I've been an unconscious LGBT activist. Perhaps what's *natural English* for one person is *unnatural English* for another. Did I say *one person*? Sorry! There I am showing my true colours!

Comment: To my ear, ***one*** is a little bit starchy - and it becomes much more so if it's *repeated*, which is why ***they*** works better. I don't find ***it means*** at all natural there either. My choice of "non-specific pronoun" here would be ***As long as you've a pastor certificate and gifts, and can analyze the Bible, you're approved and anointed by God.***